# Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: WebServiceCallout.invoke

Tags: apex, api, integration, soap

am trying to generate classes from WSDL and I get this error:

> Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: WebServiceCallout.invoke(cornerstoneClientdataservice.ClientDataServiceSoap, cornerstoneClientdataservice.SetOuLocal_element, Map, List) at line 137 column 13

The strange thing about this is that it worked in Sandbox and when I tried the same in my dev instance I get this error.
Anyone faced the same issue ?

Comment: If in isn't a custom class called WebServiceCallout as Chris suggests, can you provide some more code. The lines around where the error occurs would be useful. Ensure that the Map and the List have the correct generic types. See [WebServiceCallout.invoke](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_WebServiceCallout.htm#apex_System_WebServiceCallout_toString)

Comment: I came to know that we cannot set authorization in SOAP header. I am facing issues even after trying this solution https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AwbiIAC

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a class or variable named WebServiceCallout? If so, that would shadow the System provided implementation and likely cause this compilation error since the WSDL2Apex generator doesn't use the fully qualified class name.